# error: "expected unqualified-id before '{' token" While Creating a Template class

Tags: c++

Main Class

```
#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKET)
template<class T>
class cUI_ScrData :public GFX_Socket
#elif defined(CONFIG_QUEUE)
template<class T>
class cUI_ScrData :public cUI_MQueueTx
#else
#endif
{

bool data_changed;

public:
T data;
UINT32 id;
void set_data(T& new_data)
{
    // Some Code
}
};
```

Socket Class

```
class GFX_Socket
{
GFX_SocketImpl *gfxSocketImplObj;
public:
GFXSOCKETVSPROJ_API void Client_start();
GFXSOCKETVSPROJ_API void Client_read();
GFX_Socket();
~GFX_Socket();
void ServerWrite(void *msgbuff, int size);
void Client_start();
void Client_read();
#endif
static bool bClientStarted;
};
```

Queue Class

```
class cUI_MQueueTx
{
private:
mqd_t queue;
char ucaQueueName[QUEUE_NAME_STR_MAX_LEN];
public:
cUI_MQueueTx();
~cUI_MQueueTx();
void UI_Q_create();
};
```

Getting this error while creating a template class derived from two different classes. compiler is pointing out at "{" after #endif in Main Class.

Comment: Please indent your code, tia.

Comment: Expected when neither CONFIG_SOCKET nor CONFIG_QUEUE is defined

Comment: There should be an `#error` in that `#else`, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't be valid in case the preprocessor goes to #else.

Comment: @tambre Sure there is, look closer again!

Comment: Seems like I'm blind. Sorry.